# How to restrict same data to not show in the table on blade?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, repeat

I'm having trouble to not show same data in the table, but want to `sum` attributes' values to the old identical data's attributes.
I have 6 Models, `Purchase`, `Inventory`, `Slab`, `Scarting`, `floorTile` and `MarbleType`. `Purchase` and `Inventory` has One to one relation. Then `Inventory` further has one to one relation with `Slab`, `Scarting` and `FloorTile`. I'm fetching data using query on `Purchase` model. i.e.

```
$slabs = Purchase::where('factoryName', $factoryName)->with('inventory.slab')->get();
```

```php
{
    "id": 36,
    "marbleType_id": 2,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": "3216542",
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "45678912345",
    "phone2": "45678912345",
    "inventory_ID": 10,
    "created_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 10,
        "purchase_id": 36,
        "marbleType": "1",
        "totalSquareFt": 25,
        "priceperSquareFt": 230,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 25000,
        "standardSize_ID": "5",
        "salePrice": 250,
        "miliMeter": "6mm",
        "slab_ID": 1,
        "scarting_ID": null,
        "floorTile_ID": null,
        "created_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
            "slab": {
             "id": 1,
             "marbleName_ID": "2",
             "inventory_ID": "10",
             "created_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
             "updated_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45"
             }
        }
},
{
    "id": 55,
    "marbleType_id": 3,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": "32165421",
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "45678912345",
    "phone2": "45678912345",
    "inventory_ID": 26,
    "created_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 26,
        "purchase_id": 55,
        "marbleType": "1",
        "totalSquareFt": 12,
        "priceperSquareFt": 12,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 120,
        "standardSize_ID": "1",
        "salePrice": 15,
        "miliMeter": "6mm",
        "slab_ID": 9,
        "scarting_ID": null,
        "floorTile_ID": null,
        "created_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
            "slab": {
            "id": 9,
            "marbleName_ID": "3",
            "inventory_ID": "26",
            "created_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41",
            "updated_at": "2019-04-25 10:47:41"
            }
        }
},
{
    "id": 58,
    "marbleName_id": 2,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": null,
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "45678912345",
    "phone2": "45678912345",
    "inventory_ID": 29,
    "created_at": "2019-05-06 09:51:51",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-06 09:51:51",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 29,
        "purchase_id": 58,
        "marbleType": "1",
        "marbleName_id": 2,
        "totalSquareFt": 20,
        "priceperSquareFt": 20,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 400,
        "standardSize_ID": "4",
        "salePrice": 25,
        "miliMeter": "8mm",
        "slab_ID": 10,
        "scarting_ID": null,
        "floorTile_ID": null,
        "created_at": "2019-05-06 09:51:51",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-06 09:51:51",
            "slab": {
            "id": 10,
            "marbleName_ID": "2",
            "inventory_ID": "29",
            "created_at": "2019-05-06 09:51:51",
            "updated_at": "2019-05-06 09:51:51"
            }
        }
},
{
    "id": 56,
    "marbleType_id": 4,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": null,
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "45678912345",
    "phone2": "45678912345",
    "inventory_ID": 27,
    "created_at": "2019-05-05 20:11:52",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-05 20:11:52",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 27,
        "purchase_id": 56,
        "marbleType": "3",
        "totalSquareFt": 20,
        "priceperSquareFt": 20,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 420,
        "standardSize_ID": "3",
        "salePrice": 25,
        "miliMeter": "6mm",
        "slab_ID": null,
        "scarting_ID": null,
        "floorTile_ID": 10,
        "created_at": "2019-05-05 20:11:52",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-05 20:11:52",
        "slab": null
        }
},
{
    "id": 57,
    "marbleType_id": 9,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": null,
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "45678912345",
    "phone2": "45678912345",
    "inventory_ID": 28,
    "created_at": "2019-05-05 20:32:41",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-05 20:32:41",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 28,
        "purchase_id": 57,
        "marbleType": "2",
        "totalSquareFt": 31,
        "priceperSquareFt": 12,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 400,
        "standardSize_ID": "1",
        "salePrice": 15,
        "miliMeter": "8mm",
        "slab_ID": null,
        "scarting_ID": 4,
        "floorTile_ID": null,
        "created_at": "2019-05-05 20:32:41",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-05 20:32:42",
        "slab": null
        }
},
{
    "id": 59,
    "marbleType_id": 12,
    "fname": "Sama",
    "lname": "Jojo",
    "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
    "cnic": null,
    "area": "Johar town",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "province": "Punjab",
    "phone1": "12345678945",
    "phone2": "45678945645",
    "inventory_ID": 30,
    "created_at": "2019-05-06 10:14:35",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-06 10:14:35",
        "inventory": {
        "id": 30,
        "purchase_id": 59,
        "marbleType": "2",
        "totalSquareFt": 12,
        "priceperSquareFt": 12,
        "totalPurchasePrice": 122,
        "standardSize_ID": "1",
        "salePrice": 12,
        "miliMeter": "8mm",
        "slab_ID": null,
        "scarting_ID": 5,
        "floorTile_ID": null,
        "created_at": "2019-05-06 10:14:35",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-06 10:14:35",
        "slab": null
        }
}
```

This query gets all data, and using foreach loop i'm just getting only `Slab`s' data, Loop is as follows:

```php
foreach ($slabs as $slab) {
   if ($slab->inventory->slab_ID != NULL) {
       $marble_id = $slab->inventory->slab->marbleName_ID;
       $slab->marble = MarbleType::where('id', $marble_id)->get();
   }else {
       $slab->marble = [];
   }
}
```

As you can at `Slab` id '1' and '10' both have same `marbleName_ID`. I'm showing this data on blade in the table format, but i want if specific `MarbleName_ID` has been iterated through the loop once, and when it comes again in the future iteration then not to show it in the table but Add this Second `marbleName_ID`'s attributes' values (i.e. `totalSquareFt` and `totalPurchasePrice`) to previous same `marbleName_ID`'s attributes' values.

Here is the code of blade:

```
@foreach($slabs  as $slab )
    @foreach($slab->marble as $mar)
        <tr>
            @if($slab->inventory->marbleType == 1)
            <td> Slab </td>
            @endif
            <td>{{ $mar->marbleType }}</td>
            <td>{{ $slab->inventory->totalSquareFt }}</td>
            <td>{{ $slab->inventory->totalPurchasePrice }}</td>
            <td>{{ date('M j, Y h:ia' , strtotime( $slab->created_at )) }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach    
@endforeach
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it `marbleName_ID` or `marbleType_ID`? Your output data seems to have different key names.

Comment: Its `marbleName_ID` . Key names are not different. `marbleType` is something else.

Comment: Infact `marbleType` is the model name, while `marbleName_ID` is the foreign key of `marbleType` in `Inventory` Table